# How to access container within an openshift pod

Tags: openshift, docker-container

I've couple of containers inside an openshift POD. Each container is running two different applications say ContainerOne (ApplicationOne), ContainerTwo(ApplicationTwo) how can I access each of these containers?

Comment: Have you looked at using ``oc rsh`` command, including its ``--container`` option, or the feature of the web console to access running pods/containers?

Answer (score 10):

First find the pod:  `oc get pods`

Second task is to list all containers `oc describe pod/NAME_OF_YOUR_POD`

Third is to connect to the container by `oc rsh --container CONTAINERNAME PODNAME`

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "access". I usually employ `oc exec -it $pod -c $container bash` in such situations (w/o `-c $container` for pods with only single containers). `$pod` and `$container` can e.g. be learned from `oc describe pods`.